# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate has no MS-Reports Template Installed

Tags: visual-studio-2013

In a winform application I am trying to create a report in visual studio 2013, but when I want to add the microsoft report designer I don't find the template.

How can I to install or add .rdlc report designer in Visual Studio 2013.